# Streamline MSSQL backups using Veeam

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am looking for advice on managing backups using Veeam and optimizing storage space for backups.

We have about 2TB across 20 DB

My current backups are

**Image Level  (Veeam)**

1. Replication to DR every 1hr (excluding native backup volume)
2. Backup to DR nightly (excluding native backup volume) (different disk array to replications), 45D, 4W, 12M, 7Y  retention
3. Push to offsite repository nightly 7D

**SQL Native**

1. Nightly backup to local server (different re disk array), 1D Retention
2. 15 min transaction log backups to same folder as nightly
3. 10min FTP push native SQL backup to DR with 7D retention

I am pretty sure there is some redundant duplication here, I have been looking into Veeam and it  looks like it can handle the transaction log backups as well. If this is the case, are native backups still required? I would feel uneasy not having them but that could just be my lack of knowledge in that side of Veeam.  Or is there something else that stands out that i should change?

Veeam documentation https://helpcenter.veeam.com/evaluation/backup/vsphere/en/sql_backup_and_restore.html

**EDIT**

1. Our RPO is 30 minutes and our RTO is 2 hours

Comment: We use Veeam for daily server backups, and SQL Native does all the rest.
I am unsure about the Veeam backups through SQL but make sure that the log backups are indeed truncating the log files, otherwise they will just keep growing to huge proportions. But you are correct in that you have duplication there.
With my limited knowledge of Veeam, i would just remove the Hourly Veeam backup.
In addition, if you have Veeam do the database backups, then you need to grant it access to the database aswell, which may not be ideal?